# I'm a novice user trying to see my pc desktop on my laptop. Using Windows 11 home. is this possible?

Tags: windows, windows-11-v22h2

User is not comfortable with the cloud and would like to see/work on the desktop of the PC from both the PC and the laptop

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software Many people use TeamViewer or Chrome Remote Desktop

Comment: Are both computers using Windows Home?

Comment: You can also use Radmin Server and Viewer   (Server goes on the Desktop)